# CSS to fill container with image while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

For what it is worth, I am using [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/):

I have two divs in a single row. I would like to fill the entire right div in its entitreity with an image that maintains its aspect ratio.

That is, rather than distorting the image, I would like to scale the image until the shortest side reaches 100%, while the longer side is hidden beyond the bounds of the container.

I don't have a preference on whether this is done with an img tag or a css background image.

Here is what I have so far, but the image gets distorted as the window is resized:

```
#demo {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    img {
        min-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting it as a background image in the css and then use : background-size:cover; or....  background-size:contain; depending on your preference/need. But you may need to set the div size at that point.  Such as min-width/min-hieght.

Comment: add `background-position: 50%` to horizontally centre the background image.

Answer (score -1):

try with `height:auto` and `width:px or %`

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
```